# Como adquirir informações do CEI (Canal Eletrônico do Investidor)?

Tags: api, vba, importação, matemática

Perdoem minha leiguice, mas existe uma API que me possibilite puxar as negociações de um usuário, conhecendo o login e senha do mesmo ?

Ou seria o caso de fazer um crawler ?

Eu vi que vários serviços como [Kinvo](https://www.kinvo.com.br) e [TradeMap](https://www.trademap.com.br) tem essa funcionalidade, e fiquei interessado em tentar implementar em uma planilha, como vocês fariam ?

Comment: to precisando fazer a mesma coisa em python... por acaso vc ja fez?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SportaCub boa noite, tem sim. Usando Excel VBA. Também sou usuário, iniciante, do CEI. Talvez ajuda que vou te dar é parcial, entrar no CEI com VBA porém espero com isso darmos inicio a uma jornada de aprendizado juntos, vou aprendendo também como usar e automatizando algumas coisas e te ajudando com isso.

Primeiro passo é configurar as referências.

no IDE do VBA vá em *Ferramentas* > *Referências* em seguida marque as opções: **Microsoft Internet Controls** e **Microsoft HTML Object Library**

Segue o código, baste executar.

```
Const url_CEI As String = "https://cei.b3.com.br/CEI_Responsivo/"

Const CPF_CNPJ As String = "<seu CPF/CNPJ>"
Const Senha As String = "<sua senha>

Sub CEI_Bot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim result As String

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate url_CEI

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        'CPF/CNPJ
        Set htmlDoc = objIE.document
        Set htmlColl = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")
        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If htmlInput.Name = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtLogin" Then
                htmlInput.Value = CPF_CNPJ
                Exit For
            End If
        Next htmlInput

        'Senha
        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If htmlInput.Name = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSenha" Then
                htmlInput.Value = Senha
                Exit For
            End If
        Next htmlInput

        'Entrar
        For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
            If htmlInput.Name = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogar" Then
                htmlInput.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next htmlInput
End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Paulo, me deu uma ótima luz do processo !